# A frame in my activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, frame

I would like to know have 2 layouts in one layout/activity, like a "Frame" system.
Is it possible with Android ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply put layouts inside other layouts.

An example: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html